# About the Properties of Perspective Projection to Lower Dimension

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, projective-module, dimension-theory-analysis

I know this is loose and generic, but I just need to check my logic and if there is any reference or method ye may refer to, will be very much appreciated.

I have a function $f(\vec{v})$ which only works for $\vec{v} \in {\rm I\!R}^3$.

The problem is that I have another vector $\vec{u} = \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6\}\in {\rm I\!R}^6$ which I need to process by that function.

---

**My question:**

Does it make sense mathematically to [perspective project](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2879867) the first three dimensions and get $\vec{u^\prime} = \{a_1^\prime, a_2^\prime , a_3^\prime\} \in {\rm I\!R}^3$ , and to project the second three dimensions and get $\vec{u^{\prime\prime}} = \{a_4^{\prime\prime}, a_5^{\prime\prime} , a_6^{\prime\prime}\} \in {\rm I\!R}^3$. Then apply $f(\vec{u^\prime})$ and  $f(\vec{u^{\prime\prime}})$. And finally define a function $g(f(\vec{u^\prime}), f(\vec{u^{\prime\prime}}))$ to process the results (e.g. sum, mean or variance..etc)?

Or if there is any other approach, hints or suggestions?

Many Thanks.

Comment: The process you describe is perfectly valid from a purely formal point of view. However, to decide whether it makes sense we need more context. What are you trying to do? What do those vectors represent? What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando Thanks very much for your comment. The function $f(\vec{v})  \in {\rm I\!R}^3$ uses the inputted vector in further calculation of a parallelepiped volume. I was thinking if I can use it in higher dimension to produce a result defined by a set of of parallelepipeds (sum of them ..etc). Please write your answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

The process you describe is perfectly valid from a purely formal point of view. However, to decide whether it makes sense we need more context. What are you trying to do? What do those vectors represent? What do you hope to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks. Can your refer to a reference about the properties of Projection from higher dimensions to lower dimensions?

Comment: Any undergrad linear algebra text has what you need

Comment: no it has not! Any by the way, I gave ya a context in my comment above though.

Comment: @Mike of you have a 6 dimensional parallelepiped, there is a different way to compute its volume. Is that what you're after?