# Project high dimensional vectors onto low dimensional plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to project a set of 4-dimensional vectors to a 2-dimensional plane for visualization purposes. For example, V=(x0, y0, z0, w0), the plane is defined by (y=ys, w=ws). From the link [Projection of high dimensional vectors to lower dimensional space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/458843/projection-of-high-dimensional-vectors-to-lower-dimensional-space), I find that $$p=A(A^TA)^{−1}A^TV$$ can do the projection. However, how to formulate matrix $A$ for my case since my plane is not the XY-plane?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it correctly, but isn't simply $(x,y,z,w)\mapsto (0,y,0,w)$ the projection you're looking for?

Comment: @Berci I think it's not. If the plane is YW plane, the projection is (y0, w0). But the plane is defined by (y=ys, w=ws), the coordinates of the plane is not starting from origin anymore, right?

Comment: I don't get your notation. What do you mean by $(y=ys,\ w=ws)$? Is $s$ a parameter?

Comment: @Berci ys and ws are two predefined numbers, just to make them different from y0 and w0.

Comment: Ahh. Then just translate everything by $(0,-y_s,0,w_s)$ do the projection and translate back the result.